# How to get the sum of postbalance for last transactions using postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have a table with the following attributes - openingBalance, acct_id, closingBalance, createdat, updatedat. I want to be able to get the sum of the closing balance for all the days. That is sum up the last transacting values for all the accounts.

For instance, if there is a day where an account doesn't transact, the last transacting balance of that account should still be added to the balance of that day. This is what I currently have but it's not accurate. I have checked other questions, they do not address my problem directly.

```
select date_trunc('day', createdat) last_trn_dt, sum(postbalance) bal
from
(select wallet_id,postbalance,createdat,
row_number () over (partition by wallet_id, date_trunc('day', createdat) order by createdat desc) rnk
from wallet_history)a
where rnk = 1
group by date_trunc('day', createdat)
```

I am using postgresql for this query. Just have in mind that you want to get the available balance for a bank at a given date. This gives a better perspective to what I am trying to solve.

I have edited this to include sample of the data. Here is the data.

```
+-----------+--------------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| wallet_id | postbalance  | walletaction |        createdat        |        updatedat        |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|       469 | 47361.80945  | DEBIT        | 2022-09-15 16:21:45.584 | 2022-09-15 16:21:45.584 |
|       574 | 144102.1975  | CREDIT       | 2022-09-15 16:21:56.192 | 2022-09-15 16:21:56.192 |
|      1460 | 1984.8       | DEBIT        | 2022-09-15 16:21:58.022 | 2022-09-15 16:21:58.022 |
|      1216 | 124192.22005 | CREDIT       | 2022-09-15 16:22:17.567 | 2022-09-15 16:22:17.567 |
|      1766 | 19903.95     | CREDIT       | 2022-09-15 16:22:25.515 | 2022-09-15 16:22:25.515 |
|      1221 | 16201.0967   | CREDIT       | 2022-09-15 16:22:54.27  | 2022-09-15 16:22:54.27  |
|       883 | 4422.4       | CREDIT       | 2022-09-15 16:22:56.366 | 2022-09-15 16:22:56.366 |
|      1356 | 53040.0      | CREDIT       | 2022-09-15 16:23:38.216 | 2022-09-15 16:23:38.216 |
|       817 | 1839.875     | DEBIT        | 2022-09-15 16:23:39.639 | 2022-09-15 16:23:39.639 |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I want the output to look like this.

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|     DATE     |             | BALANCE        
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| "2022-10-01" |             | 4565677840  |
| "2022-10-02" |             | 66774889.37 |
| "2022-10-03" |             | 77884884.98 |
| "2022-10-04" |             | 8888897443  |
| "2022-10-05" |             | 8888897433  |
| "2022-10-06" |             | 3347773992  |
| "2022-10-07" |             | 88888974442 |
| "2022-10-08" |             | 8888897442  |
| "2022-10-09" |             | 88888974242
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: post the table you have and the desired result

Comment: Please define "for all the days" exactly, show your table definition and some sample data (ideally add a fiddle), and disclose your version of Postgres.

Comment: Postgres version is 14.2. For all the days I posted the sample earlier. 2021-09-16, 2022-10-07, i will do that now

Comment: Please see [Senseful Solutions](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) to create a well formatted textual table for your sample data. Once created past it into your question between lines containing only ```.  Note it is not necessary to include each column from the row but only those pertinent to the question.

Comment: Well your data table and output are now readable, thanks you for that. However, the output clearly does not follow from the input sample. The input shows a single day, actually within a couple minutes. The output shows a date span of 9 days beginning 17days after the input. Please post the output expected from the given input.

Comment: @Belayer the date span is dummy. I just want output that is similar with the initial table that was posted. Thanks